# Remove the word 'and' in XSLT using translate function

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to remove the word '*and*' from a string using the translate function rather than using a replace .

for instance:

```
 <xsl:variable name="nme" select="translate(./Name/text(), ',:, '')" />
```

in addition to ",:" i would like to remove the word '*and*' as well. Please suggest.

Comment: Am limited to XSLT 1.0  Version

Comment: translate() is used to replace characters and can't be used to replace a sequence of characters(String). You must call a template to replace a string.

Comment: It's not possible to use the translate() function to replace words, only individual characters. Use a named recursive template instead. You also need to clarify what a exactly does *word* mean in this context: you probably don't want to change "Sandy" into "Sy". OTOH, the word "and" can be followed by numerous punctuation characters, not only by a space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `translate` function can't do this, it can only remove or replace single characters, not multi-character strings.  Like so many things in XSLT 1.0 the escape route is a recursive template, the simplest version being:

```
<xsl:template name="removeWord">
  <xsl:param name="word" />
  <xsl:param name="text" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $word)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $word)" />
      <xsl:call-template name="removeWord">
        <xsl:with-param name="word" select="$word" />
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $word)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And then call this template when you define the `nme` variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="nme">
  <xsl:call-template name="removeWord">
    <xsl:with-param name="word" select="'and'" /><!-- note quotes-in-quotes -->
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(Name, ',:', '')" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Here I'm using `translate` to remove the single characters and then passing the result to the template to remove "and".

Though as pointed out in the comments, it depends exactly what you mean by "word" - this will remove all occurrences of the string "and" including in the middle of other words, you might want to be more conservative, removing only " and" (space-and), for example.

To remove more than one word you simply call the template repeatedly, passing the result of one call as a parameter to the next

```
<xsl:variable name="noEdition">
  <xsl:call-template name="removeWord">
    <xsl:with-param name="word" select="'Edition'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(Name, ',:', '')" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="nme">
  <xsl:call-template name="removeWord">
    <xsl:with-param name="word" select="' and'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$noEdition" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: @Ian Roberts : What if i want to add one more word(multiletters) say "Edition" to the same text. Should i write another template?.

Comment: @SenthilArasu I've modified the template in my example to take the "word" as a second parameter, so you could just call it twice, passing the result of the first call to the second.

Comment: @Ian Roberts : Sorry for being such a dumb. Am not able to follow the second call. These are the two words needs to be removed ' and' ,'Edition'. Can you please modify the code now?

Comment: @IanRoberts: I will try this . But alternatively i made changes to Template to check for words like 'and' and 'Edition'. That worked for me as well.

Comment: When i implement your method, It throws stack overflow exception. I have changed the "removeAnd' to 'removeWord' in your template. It didnt work .Please help

Comment: @SenthilArasu I forgot to pass the `word` parameter down the `call-template` chain, which didn't help.  Try this version instead.