# Need to remove multiple words from a string using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to remove few words like  'and','the','for'  from a single string using the translate function rather than using a replace as am using XSLT1.0 .

for instance:

```
         <xsl:variable name="nme" select="translate(./Name/text(), ',:, '')" />
```

in addition to ",:" i would like to remove the above mentioned words as well. Please suggest.

Comment: Is something not working with what you are trying? I think you need to update your question to show more of the XSLT and the XML for us to get a better picture of what is wrong.

Comment: You have asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784081/remove-the-word-and-in-xslt-using-translate-function and received an answer which you accepted. Why post it again?